# Metric name label have prefix is other variable in prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I have a variable :

```
serviceName : label_values(go_info, name)
```

ex: "AAA-deployment"
And metric in prometheus looklike:

```
metric_name{pod="AAA-deployment-XXXXX" ,name="k8s_POD_AAA-deployment-XXXX"}
```

If you want filer metric have prefix is a constant word we can use:

```
label_values(metric_name{pod=~"CONST_PREFIX*"},name)
```

But how to filter metric_name's label have prefix is other label  in prometheus?
I try

```
label_values(metric_name{pod=~"$serviceName*"},name)
```

but it not work

Comment: you can use the regex selector: metric_name{label=~"prefix*"}:
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors

Comment: but the prefix is choose by other variable $serviceName , not constant so I think your answer is not work

Comment: could you please update/format your question? it's not obvious from the initial post))

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your issue as the information provided is not sufficient.